# CSS not showing on Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

I tried using the code on the main bootstrap page as well as using a bootstrap generator. The HTML works but the CSS does not. I'm not sure what the problem is. It seems that all the classes are right to me. I would appreciate any advice. Here is the code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Bootstrap 3 Menu Generator</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Getting started</a>
        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Components</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Customize</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse { background-color: #222222}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { background-color: #}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { background-color: #080808}
.dropdown-menu { background-color: #ffffff}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-color: #428bca}
.navbar-inverse { background-image: none; }
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-image: none; }
.navbar-inverse { border-color: #080808}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand { color: #999999}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover { color: #ffffff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #999999}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #ffffff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { color: #ffffff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus { color: #ffffff}
.dropdown-menu>li>a { color: #333333}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { color: #ffffff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-top-color: #999999}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-top-color: #ffffff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-bottom-color: #999999}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-bottom-color: #ffffff}
```

Here is the head code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Use the .htaccess and remove these lines to avoid edge case issues.
       More info: h5bp.com/b/378 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Hello</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: j.mp/bplateviewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory: mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons -->

  <!-- CSS: implied media=all -->
  <!-- CSS concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!-- end CSS-->

  <!-- More ideas for your <head> here: h5bp.com/d/head-Tips -->

  <!-- All JavaScript at the bottom, except for Modernizr / Respond.
       Modernizr enables HTML5 elements & feature detects; Respond is a polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries
       For optimal performance, use a custom Modernizr build: www.modernizr.com/download/ -->
  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I think its working, check here:-
http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/w22a6/

or you are facing some other issue

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Do I add the CSS into the main css file?

Comment: Can you show me what output you are expecting from this code, as I have tried changing color, size, etc and its working

Comment: Can you show the rest of your HTML markup (especially the <head> section)?

Comment: DMX I want to change the color, font, etc.. I think the code is right too so im not sure why it is not working. First I made a normal nav menu that I customized myself but then I decided I wanted to bootstrap navbar. Khalid, I showed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom styles `style.css` should ALWAYS come **after** Bootstrap styles in page `<head>`.

SIDE NOTE: For performance reasons, you shouldn't use both `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` at the same time. You are basically making the client download the styles twice! You should use the minified version on production environments.

The same applies on `bootstrap-theme.css` and `bootstrap-theme.min.css`.

Comment: Alright thanks!!!!! That was the mistake. Just out of curiosity, why do they provide the non-minified version?

Comment: For development environments in which developers need a "readable" CSS to troubleshoot and inspect, modify the source if needed (which is not recommended), or copy the compiled CSS rules to another CSS override file (recommended method).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your custom style sheet should place under bootstrap style sheet. That is the issue you facing